# Convert.ToInt16 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using the following code as a learning progress for myself:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub BtnAntwoord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAntwoord.Click

        Dim testNummer As Integer
        Dim uitkomst As Single
        Dim waarde1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummers1)
        Dim waarde2 As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummers2)

        uitkomst = (waarde1 * waarde2)

        testNummer = Convert.ToString(uitkomst)


        MsgBox(testNummer)
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I am trying to accomplish is a small window with 2 textfields and a button wich, when pressed, presents the answer to the question "waarde 1 * waarde2"  in a popup window.

When I execute this code, the following error is presented:

```
 InvalidCastException was unhandled
```

and the line "waarde1 As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummers1)" is highlited

I am not looking for an answer per se, just the understanding as to why this does not work, seeing as I am extremely new to vb.net and I am trying to expand my knowledge of the language.

Comment: I wonder if you're working with VB6 code in vb.net? In VB6 the `.Text` is the default property.

Comment: @MarkHurd How do I know what code I am using? Im working in Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 express

Comment: It was just that the code would have worked effectively as is in VB6, so I wondered if you might have been working from a VB6 tutorial or something.

Comment: I was not using any tutorial as an example, i thought I had enough base to start making stuff on my own haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `txtNummers1` and `txtNummers2` are textboxes then you should write

```
    Dim waarde1 As Short = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummers1.Text)
    Dim waarde2 As Short = Convert.ToInt16(txtNummers2.Text)
```

You can't convert a `TextBox` type to an Integer type. You convert the Text (a string type) property of a TextBox to an Integer supposing that this property contains in effect a number.
Also, why convert to a 16bit numeric type and then assign the result to a 32bit type?

A better approach is the following

```
    Dim waarde1 As Short 
    Dim testNum as String = txtNummers1.Text
    if Int16.TryParse(testNum, waarde1) Then
         Console.WriteLine("It is a 16 bit number " + waarde1.ToString)
    else
         Console.WriteLine("Not a 16 bit number " + waarde1.ToString)
```

[Here MSDN on TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot! the .text is to tell the code that I am getting it from the textbox?

Comment: TextBox class contains the Text property. This property receive the text typed by the user or display the Text that you set programmatically.